# Emacs does not react when I press C-. (dot/period)

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, agda-mode

I am learning Agda and when I type <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-.</kbd> there is no reaction in my Emacs. I can type either <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> or <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>M-.</kbd> and then I will be told that these bindings are not defined. But when I try to type <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-.</kbd> the mini-buffer only shows `C-c` and it seems that Emacs is waiting for the next key binding. So how should I fix this problem?

I am using a MacOS. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What does `C-h` `b` or `C-h` `k` `C-c` `C-.` show?

Comment: @choroba Thanks for editing.  `C-h` `b` shows that `C-c` `C-.` is for agda2-goal-and-context-and-inferred.

Comment: @choroba `C-h` `k` `C-c` `C-.` does not work when I type `C-.` and it will wait as I mentioned in the question. It is `C-c-` in the buffer and no reaction when I type `C-.`

Comment: Do you run emacs in the terminal or as a GUI application? If you try to run it the other way run, is the behaviour the same?

Comment: What happens if you type `M-x` and run the command `agda2-goal-and-context-and-inferred`?

Comment: @EricIhli Thanks a lot. It works as I expect. By the way, emacs gives me a hint that I could do that by `C-c` `C-.`

Comment: @choroba I use GUI application. I just tried running emacs in the terminal and its behaviour is the same as GUI application.